# How do I detect when text is inserted dynamically in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code i want to know how to detect when text is inserted dynamically in input field

```
<input id="test"><br /> 
<a href="#">Click me</a>

$("#test").on("input", function() {
  alert("Change to " + this.value);
});
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("#test").val("In clicks we trust.");
});
```

[line to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/fSUd8/)

Comment: Dynamically inserted? As in programatically from the code??

Comment: "The title and the code should say it all.", Sorry, but I don't get it.. :(

Comment: @tymeJV I don't know what programatically means, but perhaps I have misused the term dynamically. What I wanted to say is that the value inserted into the input field comes from the code and is not typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for a `change` event, also, you'll have to trigger this after programatically adding text:

```
$("#test").on("change", function() {
    alert("Change to " + this.value);
});

$("a").on("click", function() {
    $("#test").val("In clicks we trust.").change();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fSUd8/1/

Comment: @naomik -- There's always one :\

Comment: That fires whether the input was changed directly by the user, or through code. If he really needs to tell if an input was changed via code, then I think the only way to do that would be by registering a custom event

Comment: change is not fired when text is inserted from Windows's Tablet OSK in handwriting mode.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery change() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('#test').on('change', function() {
    ...
});
```